# EasySlider 1.7 - How to move the number buttons on to the image?

Tags: easyslider

I've just discovered EasySlider, and it's great.  But I can't seem to find anywhere that describes how to move the number buttons from under the slider so that they are instead *on* the slider.

Can anyone suggest how this can be acheived?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can take its control via CSS the target is `ol#controls` 
If you add this to your stylesheet it will move the numbers on the slider:

```
ol#controls { margin: -30px 0 0 0 !important; }
```

Comment: I inserted that line but it seems to put the buttons *under* the scrolling images not on top of.  (I can confirm this by changing it to -20, then I can see the bottoms of the boxes sticking out from under the image.

Comment: So you want this to be at top of the slider you can increase the number like this: `margin: -120px 0 0 0 ! important;` adjust it to your needs

Comment: No, my point is that I can't see the numbers because they are *behind* the sliding images.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh I see, add this new line and let me know if it works `ol#controls { margin: -30px 0 0 0 !important; z-index:9999 !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

just to make you clear, I achieved the following result --

http://i55.tinypic.com/x2q8ie.jpg

with the following edits in the css for ol#controls --

http://i52.tinypic.com/1tqzyq.jpg

adding an !important as nima suggested will ensure that your custom styles override the default styles of easyslider.