# easySlider 1.7 How do i move the next / previous control buttons above slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im having oodles of fun with the easySlider 1.7 implementing it was easy the only change I want to do is to move the next and previous buttons above the slider not underneath, any ideas on how to accomplish this?, I've tried putting

```
ol#controls { margin: -30px 0 0 0 !important; }
```

in my css from [EasySlider 1.7 - How to move the number buttons on to the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377561/easyslider-1-7-how-to-move-the-number-buttons-on-to-the-image) but no luck. Here is my full code any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="easySlider1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider();
    }); 
</script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin:0;
            padding:40px;
            background:#fff;
            font:80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color:#555;
            line-height:180%;
        }
        #slider ul, #slider li{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            list-style:none;
            }
        #slider li{ 
            width:946px;
            height:auto;
            overflow:hidden; 
            }
        span#prevBtn{}
        span#nextBtn{}


    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slider">
    <ul>                
        <li><img src="../Desktop/slide1.png" alt="slide1" width="946" height="555" /></li>
        <li><img src="../Desktop/slide1.png" alt="slide1" width="946" height="555" /></li>
        <li><img src="../Desktop/slide1.png" alt="slide1" width="946" height="555" /></li>
        <li><img src="../Desktop/slide1.png" alt="slide1" width="946" height="555" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css which will adjust the position of your buttons

```
        span#firstBtn {
            margin-top: -400px;
            position: absolute;
            width: auto;
        }
```

this works for span#firstBtn,  span#nextBtn,  span#prevBtn and span#lastBtn .

hope this helps :)